# App Engine can't find default credentials to connect to Firestore in Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a NextJS Typescript app running on Google App Engine. It fetches data from Firestore and everything works fine. In order to improve the speed of the app I'm experimenting new data fetching infrastructure in which the server listens to Firestore collections and updates all the data to JSON files in the tmp folder when changes are made in Firestore. This way all the data is up-to-date and available to the App Engine all the time. Locally this works like a charm.

There are some obvious things I need to improve, but the next step for me is to run a dev project in GCP and see if my memory usage is ok and if it works as quickly as I hope etc. But the problem is that when I change my NextJS infra to include a custom server, the connection between App Engine and Firestore vanishes.

The problem I'm seeing on GCP logs is:

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/workspace/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:180:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:526:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
    at async GoogleAuth.getClient (/workspace/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:558:17)
    at async GrpcClient._getCredentials (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:145:24)
    at async GrpcClient.createStub (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:308:23)
```

The actual error message in the client is "502 Bad Gateway – nginx".

Earlier I had a basic NextJS app which has frontend pages and backend API routes. The routes connect to Firestore and serve that data to correct users etc. The main difference is that I've added a custom server that initiates the listeners:

```
import { Firestore } from '@google-cloud/firestore';
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import next from 'next';
import fs from 'fs';
import os from 'os';

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

let firestoreListeners: { [collectionId: string]: () => void } = {};

const unsubscribeAllListeners = () => {
    for (const collectionId of Object.keys(firestoreListeners)) {
        console.log('unsubscribing from', collectionId);
        firestoreListeners[collectionId]();
    }
    firestoreListeners = {};
};

const skippedCollections = ['analytics', 'pageRevisions', 'newsItemRevisions'];

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();

    unsubscribeAllListeners();

    const firestoreSettings = {} as FirebaseFirestore.Settings;
    if (process.env.GCP_KEYFILE_NAME) {
        firestoreSettings.keyFilename = process.env.GCP_KEYFILE_NAME;
    }

    const firestoreData: {
        [collectionId: string]: {
            [id: string]: any;
        };
    } = {};
    const firestore = new Firestore(firestoreSettings);

    firestore.listCollections().then((collections) => {
        for (const collection of collections) {
            if (
                !firestoreListeners[collection.id] &&
                !skippedCollections.includes(collection.id)
            ) {
                console.log('listening to', collection.id);
                firestoreData[collection.id] = {};
                const listener = firestore
                    .collection(collection.id)
                    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                        firestoreData[collection.id] = {};
                        for (const doc of snapshot.docs) {
                            firestoreData[collection.id][doc.id] = {
                                _id: doc.id,
                                ...doc.data(),
                            };
                        }
                        if (!fs.existsSync(os.tmpdir() + '/data')) {
                            fs.mkdirSync(os.tmpdir() + '/data');
                        }
                        fs.writeFileSync(
                            os.tmpdir() + `/data/${collection.id}.json`,
                            JSON.stringify(firestoreData[collection.id])
                        );

                        console.log(
                            'updated',
                            collection.id,
                            'with',
                            snapshot.docs.length,
                            'docs'
                        );
                    });
                firestoreListeners[collection.id] = listener;
            }
        }
    });

    server.all('*', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        return handle(req, res);
    });
    server.listen(port, (err?: any) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(
            `> Ready on localhost:${port} - env ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
        );
    });
    server.on('close', function () {
        unsubscribeAllListeners();
    });
    process.on('beforeExit', () => {
        unsubscribeAllListeners();
    });
});
```

The build and deploy scripts are ok, it works if I take the listener logic out of the equation and just deploy the custom server.

What's the problem? Is it some nginx problem or do I have something else off?

Comment: It works if I move the listener logic to /_ah/warmup route which will then be initiated with every  but with that it's super hard to make sure that I only have one listener per instance. But the key is probably that it works with the listener logic in the NextJS API route, but not when I have the listener logic done with the server.

Comment: Kindly post your comment as an answer so that the community would find this helpful.

Comment: I don't feel like my comment is really an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem apparently is that I cannot initiate my Firestore connection before `listen` or even at the `listen` callback. I have to do it a bit later (to give GAE a possibility to authenticate for Firestore?).

When I moved my listeners to listen to all endpoints, it worked. Below is a solution that helped with the problem. I don't feel it's that beautiful, but gets the job done.

```
import { Firestore } from '@google-cloud/firestore';
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import next from 'next';
import fs from 'fs';
import os from 'os';

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

let firestoreListeners: { [collectionId: string]: () => void } = {};

const unsubscribeAllListeners = () => {
    for (const collectionId of Object.keys(firestoreListeners)) {
        console.log('unsubscribing from', collectionId);
        firestoreListeners[collectionId]();
    }
    firestoreListeners = {};
};

const skippedCollections = ['analytics', 'pageRevisions', 'newsItemRevisions'];

export const firestoreData: {
    [collectionId: string]: {
        [id: string]: any;
    };
} = {};

let listenersInitiated = false;

const initiateListeners = () => {
    if (listenersInitiated) {
        return;
    }
    const firestoreSettings = {} as FirebaseFirestore.Settings;
    if (process.env.GCP_KEYFILE_NAME) {
        firestoreSettings.keyFilename = process.env.GCP_KEYFILE_NAME;
    }
    const firestore = new Firestore(firestoreSettings);

    firestore.listCollections().then((collections) => {
        for (const collection of collections) {
            if (
                !firestoreListeners[collection.id] &&
                !skippedCollections.includes(collection.id)
            ) {
                console.log('listening to', collection.id);
                firestoreData[collection.id] = {};
                const listener = firestore
                    .collection(collection.id)
                    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                        firestoreData[collection.id] = {};
                        for (const doc of snapshot.docs) {
                            firestoreData[collection.id][doc.id] = {
                                _id: doc.id,
                                ...doc.data(),
                            };
                        }
                        if (!fs.existsSync(os.tmpdir() + '/data')) {
                            fs.mkdirSync(os.tmpdir() + '/data');
                        }
                        fs.writeFileSync(
                            os.tmpdir() + `/data/${collection.id}.json`,
                            JSON.stringify(firestoreData[collection.id])
                        );

                        console.log(
                            'updated',
                            collection.id,
                            'with',
                            snapshot.docs.length,
                            'docs'
                        );
                    });
                firestoreListeners[collection.id] = listener;
            }
        }
    });
    listenersInitiated = true;
};

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();
    unsubscribeAllListeners();

    server.all('*', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        initiateListeners();
        return handle(req, res);
    });
    server.listen(port, (err?: any) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(
            `> Ready on localhost:${port} - env ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
        );
    });
    server.on('close', function () {
        console.log('Closing');
        unsubscribeAllListeners();
    });
    process.on('beforeExit', () => {
        console.log('Closing');
        unsubscribeAllListeners();
    });
});
```

According to my initial tests this works very nicely in GAE. When setting the app.yaml settings correctly, it provides nice speed with low costs.

This does not really handle listeners failing if a server instance lives for a long time and also, it might initiate too many listeners, but the initial results of my tests are promising!